# Masterpage footer alignment doesn't align correctly

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, nopcommerce

I am having a hard time putting footer content at the bottom of the page, at this moment it's right aligned and I have no idea what else to do to put below the content.

See the image attachment to see how does it look at this moment:

[image: screenshot]

The content from the master page you can find it below:

```
       <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 
                      <!-- FOOTER -->
       <div class="footer">          
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/nopBlue/icons/facebook.png" CssClass="facebook"  />
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/nopBlue/icons/twitter.png" CssClass="twitter" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/nopBlue/icons/linkedin.png" CssClass="linkedin" />         
        </div> 
        <!-- End FOOTER -->
```

and the css file for the footer:

```
.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    width:100%;
}
```

### Update

Here is the code from the browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/laziale/seZT8/

### Second update

Here is the online url for the problem page:

http://www.5280.bz/d/nopCommerceSite/Cellphones.aspx

Comment: can you provide the output html instead of the asp code? and preferably strip it down to the essentials ?

Comment: And maybe first run a validation check, i see html errors around line 400: <a href="#"><li class="inactive">Shopping cart</a>

Comment: @ptriek please check the link for the output code, I updated my post. Thanks for helping

Comment: the styling isn't getting applied so there's no way to see the problem in your jsfiddle

Comment: mhm, i'm afraid that's not enough to provide an answer, i cannot reproduce the problem - you don't have an online link? that would really help...

Comment: @ptriek please check here: http://www.5280.bz/d/nopCommerceSite/Cellphones.aspx Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you should fix all your [validation](http://validator.w3.org/) errors, lot's of thing to be fixed...
- The positioning is caused by to missing `</div>` - the footer is nested within the newsletter block. Add two times  `</div>` just before `<!-- End RIGHT Side -->`
- Then change #footer css to:

  ```
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  ```
- That should fix it...

Comment: check now, the markup is fixed and the images are on the left now

Comment: you still have to remove the position:absolute from your .footer, and add text-align:center (i meant .footer instead of #footer in my answer)...

Comment: Yeaaah thanks, I was updating wrong css :). Have a good day everyone thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the width to 100%;

.footer {

```
color: #4e5766;   
padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;  
margin: 0px auto; 
text-align: center; 
line-height: normal; 
width:100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**try to add Float:left**

color: #4e5766;
padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px auto; 
text-align: center; 
line-height: normal; 
width:100%;

```
Float:left
```

Comment: doesn't help, stays the same. Thanks for helping me